# How many vertices/nodes are too many in a graph and stop being beneficial?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, graph, data-modeling

**Background**

I'm working on a project that requires me to keep track of transactions as well as the flow of items in a game.
In order to do that, I'm storing those transaction in a graph db (Orient-DB).

A Shop in the game can have zero or more basekts each of which can hold one type of item. So when a Player sells something, the sold items (if any) will be placed into the respective basket and the transaction is complete.

**Question**

I'm not entirely sure how to model that behavior properly though. I can think of two more or less sane ways to represent this, but don't know which representation is best for this scenario.

*Things I need to know at any given time*

- how did item x end up in basket y

  - which transaction was responsible for that?
  - which Player sold that item?
- which shops/players did item x pass through previously
- which Player did business with shop x (and the reverse)?

*Option A:*

[image: Option A]

I create a transaction vertex and create edges between that, any and all `Items`, the `Basket` and the `Player` in question.
Downside is, I have to add data to the `contains` edges, to specify which item went into which `Basket` (here in light blue).

*Option B:*

[image: Option B]

I add additional nodes, to link transactions with `Baskets` and `Items`.
Here I get to represent all data in the graph in the form of vertices and edges but I'm introducing yet more hops to get from `Shop` to `Player`.

---

The downside of *A* that could see is that when I want to get the items of a given transaction, I have to do additional queries if I want to know how an `Item` ended up in that specific `Basket`.

Which way should I go? Is there a better option?

Would adding a direct edge between Player and Shop be benefitial (with a reference to the transaction as property) to reduce unnecessary hops when all I want to know is, who went to a Shop?

I think this question boils down to, how many vertices are too many and when do I separate this into different queries (basically like a `JOIN` in relational databases)?

I did consider a transaction log for this, but some requirements that need to be queried would make this a hell to `JOIN`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the background to this question - are you using a graph database, or are you using graphs as an abstract model of the process, or something else?

Comment: @Jules I am using a graph database (Orient-DB) and want to store those transactions. Will update the question to make this clearer - thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A day after posting the question, I came to the realization that I was holding the problem wrong. My question about adding an edge between Shop and Player was already a step in the right direction.

I don't need to solve my three problems with one graph structure.

When querying how an Item ended up in a Basket, the transactions are only secondary. The important part is the "flow", which I can easily traverse when there's a link between the Basket and the Item.

Also, when I want to know the shops frequented by players, I just need to add an edge to that. If I want to know more details about a specific transaction, I can always query the referenced Items.

Lastly, a short representation of the model I ended up using:

[image: Solution graph]